# do flavors transfer?

Tags: cleaning, cast-iron

I brought out my old cast iron pan and scrubbed it with salt and seasoned it yesterday.  I have used it in the past for a few things but not much.  I want to start using it on a regular basis.  Question:  If I am only using water to "wash" it after cooking, won't some of the flavors transfer to my next item?  For example, if I saute onions and then want to make pancakes next.  Thank you!

Comment: Why not use some detergent?

Comment: Trying to avoid the use of soap as recommended by most.

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure that you season your pan correctly.  Once your cast iron pan is seasoned; that is, a layers of oil have polymerized on the surface, cleaning it with soap and water is not a problem. While working to build up a good seasoning, you can clean by using salt as an abrasive and wiping out well.  Both of these methods will eliminate the possibility of flavor contamination.

Comment: I was just trying to follow the advice of NOT using soap/detergent.  :)

Comment: @Diane, maybe not the best advice.  There is no reason to avoid soap and water on a well-seasoned cast iron pan.   Mine is soaking in the sink right now, in preparation for a cleaning from last night's roast chicken.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I would prefer to use soap and water and I have in the past.  My pan actually looks great and seems fine so I am not going to worry about it!